# Comma omission in a specific case

Tags: punctuation, commas

> I went, waving my hand, to my friend.

Can I omit the two commas?

> I went waving my hand to my friend.

This is what I want to write.

Comment: More idiomatically, *I **left,** waving to my friend.* There would only be the one pause, as reflected by the one comma, and there's no need to specify what you're waving unless it's something *other* than your hand (your handkerchief, perhaps?).

Comment: And *don't **go** thinking that's a good verb choice!* The verb ***to go*** (including past tense ***went*** has far more meanings than just ***to leave***. Compare *I went, waving my hand* (weird, even with the comma) and *He went looking for trouble* (perfectly idiomatic *without* a comma).

Comment: Do you mean "I went towards my friend, waving my hand as I walked" or "I went away, waving to my friend in farewell"? If it's the second one, there shouldn't be a comma after _hand_.

Comment: ["Go"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go) can mean to begin an action or apply yourself to an activity, so "he went waving" could mean he started waving or he occupied himself with waving.